# To handle closing of sysrefcursor returned from a Plsql Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have a stored procedure defined as below:

```
Create or replace Stored Procedure demo(Id in number, emp_dtl our sys_refcursor)

Begin

Open emp_dtl for
Select* from emp where empid=p_id;

End;
```

The above stored procedure is directly called by an API. While calling this Stored procedure we are receiving ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence and ORA-01001: INVALID CURSOR. we are receiving this error intermittently. I googled the error and looks like we get this error when the cursor closed before we fetch from the cursor. Can somebody please help me to understand how can we resolve this.

Comment: That would require tracing through the rest of your code, the code that calls this procedure.

Comment: That is a dotnet code that just fetches this cursor value in a variable and then further binds this value to table_name.column_name

Comment: Also to add that this error occurs once in 1000 times.

Comment: You will have to get help from dotnet folks who can look at your client code. The problem isn't in Oracle, but how you are working with the cursor in your client. If you close a cursor, you can't fetch from it again. You'll have to find where you're closing the cursor.

Comment: [**ORA-01002 fetch out of sequence**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: In a host language program, a FETCH call was issued out of sequence. A successful parse-and-execute call must be issued before a fetch. This can occur if an attempt was made to FETCH from an active set after all records have been fetched. This may be caused by fetching from a SELECT FOR UPDATE cursor after a commit. A PL/SQL cursor loop implicitly does fetches and may also cause this error.

Comment: [**ORA-01001 invalid cursor**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: Either a host language program call specified an invalid cursor or the value of the MAXOPENCURSORS option in the precompiler command were too small. All cursors must be opened using the OOPEN call before being referenced in any of the following calls: SQL, DESCRIBE, NAME, DEFINE, BIND, EXEC, FETCH, and CLOSE. The Logon Data Area (LDA) must be defined by using OLON or OLOGON. If the LDA is not defined, this message is issued for the following calls: OPEN, COM, CON, ROL, and LOGOFF

Answer (score 0):

These errors can occur when the cursor is closed or if you try to fetch from a cursor that has already been closed.
To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the cursor is being handled properly.

This is the correction of your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo(p_id IN NUMBER, emp_dtl OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN emp_dtl FOR
        SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empid = p_id;

    -- Fetch data from the cursor
    -- Note: You should FETCH INTO variables here if you want to retrieve data

    -- Close the cursor when done
    CLOSE emp_dtl;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Handle any exceptions here (e.g., log the error)
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```